# Determining what the selector is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I jumped throught the different areas of [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) source that are called when you type:

```
$('.foo')
```

or

```
$('#foo')
```

to try and determine how jQuery parses the selector ( I assumed charAt() ) but wanted to verify.

I got to here:

```
    if ( selector.nodeType ) {
        this.context = this[0] = selector;
        this.length = 1;
        return this;
    }
```

But I got kind of stuck on what

```
selector.nodeType
```

does.  This [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp) says that a nodeType can be pretty much anything...so what exactly are they checking for?

The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) breaks down the possibilities further.

In summary what is this code snippet trying to accomplish regarding the selector variable?

Comment: First of all, [don't read anything on w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Second of all, I'm not looking through all of jquery's source but it looks like a quick test to see if the selector is a DOM object already, since you can pass in strings, DOM elements or read-made jquery objects as you want

Comment: Oh, you never know; I'm sure there's *some* things on there that aren't wrong, bad-practice, out-of-date and/or misrepresented.

Comment: This is usually called duck typing. They are trying to guess at what was passed. If it has a truthy "nodeType" property, they are assuming that a DOM element was passed instead of a string. A more thorough test would be `var ntype = selector.nodeType; if (ntype && Math.abs(ntype) === ntype) {`

Comment: jQuery uses Sizzle for evaluating the selectors: http://sizzlejs.com/.

Comment: @Felix..what do you mean..if it finds a string it runs this regex... `match = rquickExpr.exec( selector );`

Comment: `rquickExpr = /^(?:[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)/,`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nodeType` suggests that the object passed to the jQuery selector is a DOM node (which will generally be an element).  This allows, for instance, the following construction:

```
$(document)
```

`document` is an object that represents the document. `$(document)` builds a jQuery object based on that element.  The test for `nodeType` means that jQuery can detect whether the argument was an element, and if so simply to build the selection based on that.

You can also see this with the common construction `$(this)`:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).text()); // builds a jQuery selection based on the this
                                 // object, which is the DOM element that was 
                                 // clicked
});
```